How to action update expression
I'm using the AWS Java SDK v2 with UpdateExpression so that I can update an item without having to retrieve the item from DynamoDB.
I've managed to build the update expression but now I don't know how to action it.
DynamoDbEnhancedClient client = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
                        .dynamoDbClient(DynamoDbClient.builder().region(Region.EU_WEST_1).build())
                        .extensions(AutoGeneratedUuidExtension.create())
                        .build();

DynamoDbTable<MyClass> table = client.table("MyTable", TableSchema.fromBean(MyClass.clazz));

SetAction action = SetAction.builder()
                        .path("#optIn")
                        .value("if_not_exists(#optIn,:optInValue)")
                        .putExpressionValue(":optInValue", fromBool(true))
                        .build();

UpdateExpression updateExpression = UpdateExpression.builder()
                        .addAction(action)
                        .build();

// Now I don't know how to call table.execute(updateExpression, uniqueId);



If you don't want to read the item into memory before updating, you should use the low level client.
For the EnhancedClient you have to create a custom extension which overrides the WriteModification extension:
Create the override class:
public final class CustomExtension implements DynamoDbEnhancedClientExtension {

    @Override
    public WriteModification beforeWrite(DynamoDbExtensionContext.BeforeWrite context) {
        return WriteModification.builder()
                                .updateExpression(createUpdateExpression())
                                .build();
    }
}

Create the UpdateExpression:
private static UpdateExpression createUpdateExpression() {
    AttributeValue val = AttributeValue.builder().s("Bar").build();
    SetAction setAction = 
    SetAction.builder()
                .path("#attr")
                .value(":val")
                .putExpressionName("#attr", "attr")
                .putExpressionValue(":val", val)
                .build();

    UpdateExpression.builder()
                    .addAction(setAction)
                    .build();
}

Add the extension to the client:
DynamoDbEnhancedClient enhancedClient = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
                                                              .extensions(new CustomExtension()))
                                                              .build();


And then how do I use it @Leeroy? table.updateItem(new MyClass().withId("existing_id"))?

I'll just use the low level client since the extension will apply to all update item requests
